# Upgrading from MVC2 to MVC3 causes an exception. See description

Tags: model-view-controller, upgrade

I have looked at a lot of posts for possible duplicates but have had no luck implementing them correctly. The exception that I get is:

'HttpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior' can only be invoked before 'HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState' event is raised.

And here's my code:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string originalPath = Request.Path;
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, false);
    IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
    httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(originalPath, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string originalPath = Request.Path;
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, false);
    IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
    HttpContext.Current.Server.TransferRequest(Request.ApplicationPath);
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(originalPath, false);
}
```